# How to prevent a Ridigbody from going through walls?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a ship thats a `Rigidbody`.  The ship has a `MeshCollider` on it. This collider is set as Convex.

I've got the ground thats a programmatically created `Mesh`. That Mesh has a`MeshCollider` on it. This collider is not set as Convex.

Most of the time, this works. I don't fall through the floor. About 40% of the time I can drive through the walls.

Trying to solve this, for each wall section I added a child `GameObject` marked as static. This `GameObject` has a `BoxCollider` on it. I've sized the collider to be 0.1 larger than the section of the wall. This means the colliders overlap, and there should be no gap to fall through.

As you can see in the image below, I'm still able to drive through the wall some times.

What should I be doing so I can't drive through the walls?

[image]

I've tried:

- Adding a `Rigidbody` to the ground as well, marked as kinematic. To do this I removed the `MeshCollider` all together and used all `BoxCollider`s. I had to use all `BoxCollider`s as you can have a Convex Rigidbody. *This didn't solve the issue*.
- I Removed the `MeshCollider` from the player and use a single `BoxCollider`. At this point there are no longer any `MeshCollider`s in the scene. *This didn't solve the issue*.
- Both `Rigidbody`s are set to Continuous Collision Detection.

*I'm staring to wonder if the UNity3d Physics system works at all :/*

Comment: How are you moving the ship? Are you directly moving the position of the ship, or are you using a Rigidbody method like AddForce? By the way, don't worry, Unity's 3D physics engine "Nvidia PhysX" is actually very robust. There's a lot that can go wrong down to user error unfortunately (it happens to all of us).

Comment: @AquaGeneral - I'm using `Rigidbody.MovePosition` and `Rigidbody.MoveRotation` to make the ship's movements.

Answer (score 2):

Too many things could be the problem try of these one by one and see which one works for you.

1. If you want to use **Mesh Colliders** with convex, RigidBody Must be attached to it. Attach **RigidBody to both Object**.
2. Because you are generating walls with code, make sure that the wall you are assigning Mesh Collider has **<=** **255** triangles.**Convex Mesh Colliders** are **limited** to **255 triangles**. If the triangles of the Wall > 255,convex will **fail**.
3. Since it works sometimes but fails other times, change both the wall and the ship's the **RigidBody Collision Detection** to **Continuous Dynamic**.
4. Use **Compound Colliders**. Remove the Mesh Collider on the Ship and use multiple Box Colliders around your ship to get the desired feel of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the fixed and maximum allowed timestep. I set the "Fixed Timestamp" to `0.0005`

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html